# Emulador sem conexão à Internet

Tags: android, emulador

Pessoal hoje fui continuar minha aplicação e reparei que o emulador não estava com conexão a Internet porém eu ainda estou usando o emulador do **Android Studio** o **Nexus 5 API 25**.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julgo que isso é um problema da versão do Android Emulator que está a utilizar.
Digo isso porque me deparei com esse problema e ele desapareceu quando actualizei para a versão 26.1.2.

Para verificar qual a versão que tem instalada, nos icons da parte superior, click no icon "SDK Manager", aquele antes do ?. Na aba SDK Tools veja qual a versão do Android Emulator.

Durante esse período resolvi o problema lançando o emulador via comando:

Abra o Bloco Notas e crie um arquivo com este conteúdo([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42784657/2556111)):

```
start C:\Users\NomeUtilizador\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5X_API_24 -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

- Substitua `NomeUtilizador` pelo seu.
- Substitua `Nexus_5X_API_24`pelo nome do emulador que quer lançar
- Dê-lhe um nome e grave, depois altere a extensão de `.txt` para `.bat`.

Use-o para lançar o emulador.